# can we set render as value of vf page from LWC using lms after the component is rendered?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, pdf

can we set render as value of vf page from LWC using lms after the component is rendered ? SO that after my LWC component renders , it'll be shown as PDF from Visualforce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the renderAs, but that won't help you, as doing so is a server-side action, so you would lose the client-side state changes. In other words, the component won't be rendered then the page reloads, and your PDF would contain everything except the component. If you wanted to render a PDF, you'd want to render a DOM, then use jspdf or call an Apex method to generate the PDF (Blob.toPdf()). Even then, you'd have to use manual DOM creation in order to grab everything in the component that you wish to render as a PDF.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for the help .